# Displaying file copy progress using FSCopyObjectAsync

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, nsfilemanager, nsprogressindicator

It appears after much searching that there seems to be a common problem when trying to do a file copy and show a progress indicator relative to the amount of the file that has been copied. After spending some considerable time trying to resolve this issue, I find myself at the mercy of the StackOverflow Gods once again :-) - Hopefully one day I'll be among those that can help out the rookies too!

I am trying to get a progress bar to show the status of a copy process and once the copy process has finished, call a Cocoa method. The challenge - I need to make use of File Manager Carbon calls because NSFileManager does not give me the full ability I need.

I started out by trying to utilize the code on Matt Long's site [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/). The code got me some good distance. I managed to get the file copy progress working. The bar updates and (with some additional searching within Apple docs) I found out how to tell if the file copy process has finished...

`if (stage == kFSOperationStageComplete)`

However, I have one last hurdle that is a little larger than my leap right now. I don't know how to pass an object reference into the callback and I don't know how to call a Cocoa method from the callback once finished. This is a limit of my Carbon -> Cocoa -> Carbon understanding. One of the comments on the blog said

> "Instead of accessing the progress indicator via a static pointer, you can just use the void *info field of the FSFileOperationClientContext struct, and passing either the AppDelegate or the progress indicator itself."

Sounds like a great idea. Not sure how to do this. For the sake of everyone else that appears to bump into this issue and is coming from a non-Carbon background, based mostly upon the code from Matt's example, here is some simplified code as an example of the problem...

In a normal cocoa method:

```
CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
FSFileOperationRef fileOp = FSFileOperationCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

OSStatus status = FSFileOperationScheduleWithRunLoop(fileOp, 
                     runLoop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

if (status) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to schedule operation with run loop: %@", status);
    return NO;
}

// Create a filesystem ref structure for the source and destination and 
// populate them with their respective paths from our NSTextFields.

FSRef source;
FSRef destination;

// Used FSPathMakeRefWithOptions instead of FSPathMakeRef which is in the 
// original example because I needed to use the kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions
// to deal with file paths to remote folders via a /Volume reference

FSPathMakeRefWithOptions((const UInt8 *)[aSource fileSystemRepresentation],
    kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions, 
    &source, 
    NULL);

Boolean isDir = true;

FSPathMakeRefWithOptions((const UInt8 *)[aDestDir fileSystemRepresentation],
    kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions, 
    &destination, 
    &isDir);

// Needed to change from the original to use CFStringRef so I could convert
// from an NSString (aDestFile) to a CFStringRef (targetFilename)

CFStringRef targetFilename = (CFStringRef)aDestFile;

// Start the async copy.

status = FSCopyObjectAsync (fileOp,
             &source,
             &destination, // Full path to destination dir
             targetFilename,
             kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions,
             statusCallback,
             1.0,
             NULL);

CFRelease(fileOp);

if (status) {

    NSString * errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", 
                           [self class], status];

        NSLog(@"Failed to begin asynchronous object copy: %@", status);
}
```

Then the callback (in the same file)

```
static void statusCallback (FSFileOperationRef fileOp,
           const FSRef *currentItem,
           FSFileOperationStage stage,
           OSStatus error,
           CFDictionaryRef statusDictionary,
           void *info )
{

    NSLog(@"Callback got called.");

    // If the status dictionary is valid, we can grab the current values to 
    // display status changes, or in our case to update the progress indicator.

    if (statusDictionary)
    {

        CFNumberRef bytesCompleted;

        bytesCompleted = (CFNumberRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(statusDictionary,
                 kFSOperationBytesCompleteKey);

        CGFloat floatBytesCompleted;
        CFNumberGetValue (bytesCompleted, kCFNumberMaxType, 
                              &floatBytesCompleted);

        NSLog(@"Copied %d bytes so far.", 
                              (unsigned long long)floatBytesCompleted);

        // fileProgressIndicator is currently declared as a pointer to a 
        // static progress bar - but this needs to change so that it is a 
        // pointer passed in via the controller. Would like to have a 
        // pointer to an instance of a progress bar

        [fileProgressIndicator setDoubleValue:(double)floatBytesCompleted];
        [fileProgressIndicator displayIfNeeded];
     }

if (stage == kFSOperationStageComplete) {

    NSLog(@"Finished copying the file");

    // Would like to call a Cocoa Method here...
}

}
```

So the bottom line is how can I:

1. Pass a pointer to an instance of a progress bar from the calling method to the callback
2. Upon completion, call back out to a normal Cocoa method

And as always, help is much appreciated (and hopefully the answer will solve many of the issues and complaints I have seen in many threads!!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using the last parameter to `FSCopyObjectAsync()`, which is a struct of type `FSFileOperationClientContext`. One of the fields of that struct is `info`, which is a void* parameter that you can basically use as you see fit. Whatever you assign to that field of the struct you pass into `FSCopyObjectAsync()` will be passed in turn to your callback function as the last `info` function parameter there. A void* can be anything, including a pointer to an object, so you can use that to pass the instance of your object that you want to handle the callback.

The setup code would look like this:

```
FSFileOperationClientContext clientContext = {0}; //zero out the struct to begin with

clientContext.info = myProgressIndicator;
//All the other setup code
status = FSCopyObjectAsync (fileOp,
         &source,
         &destination, // Full path to destination dir
         targetFilename,
         kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions,
         statusCallback,
         1.0,
         &clientContext);
```

Then, in your callback function:

```
static void statusCallback (FSFileOperationRef fileOp,
       const FSRef *currentItem,
       FSFileOperationStage stage,
       OSStatus error,
       CFDictionaryRef statusDictionary,
       void *info )
{
    NSProgressIndicator* fileProgressIndicator = (NSProgressIndicator*)info;
    [fileProgressIndicator setDoubleValue:(double)floatBytesCompleted];
    [fileProgressIndicator displayIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Brian thanks!!! Now I see it, the solution seems so straightforward! I ended up initializing a class instance to handle the progress panel completely and passed that class instance into the clientContext. I was able to update the progress bar and make method calls against the class. I'll post a full solution for anyone who hasn't quite followed my last comments when I get a moment. Thanks again Brian!

Comment: @Hooligancat Can you post your full solution? I have the same problem: I would like to pass the class instance into the clientContext but I dont know how.

Comment: @FR6 - I haven't touched this code in a while, but I will take a dig through and see if I can find it for you and post the entire code. Stay tuned...

Comment: @FR6 - I know its been a while, but I never did manage to dig out this code. We canned the project and I had dumped the code base. Sorry :-( If I come across it I will still post it even though it's probably a little late for you.

Comment: @Hooligancat No problem, don't worry.

Comment: It's worth noting that Apple deprecated FSCopyObjectAsync in OSX 10.8.  Thus far, I've been unable to find an alternative that allows cancel/progress updates.  They specifically state that copyItemAtURL should be used instead, or copyfile() at the BSD/POSIX layer..