# Stop NSFileManager process

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

I am copying some data using NSFileManager:

```
success = [manager copyItemAtPath:[dirToCopyFrom stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] toPath:[dirToCopyTo stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&copyError];
```

NSFileManager seems to provide no way of stopping this process however. Is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `NSFileManager`, no.  You have to drop to the lower level `FSCopyObjectAsync` function.

For an example on how to use this function, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784230/115730).

As for how to cancel the copy, the first parameter you're going to get to your copy callback is an `FSFileOperationRef`.  Passing that parameter as the argument to `FSFileOperationCancel()` should cancel the copy. (See [this CocoaBuilder.com thread for more info](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/295163-interrupt-copyitematpath.html))

Comment: Alternative for iOS? As far as I understand this is only for Mac OS...

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question but I just stumbled upon it since I had the exact same problem; I wanted to use NSFileManager over Carbon methods and implementing a manual recursive copy, because there's just too many cases to handle, and NSFileManager does a good job of resolving errors in file operations (e.g. move between volumes, move to a mounted network path, etc). You can stop NSFileManager, basically, by inducing an error. It's not pretty, but it works properly. E.g. I used NSFileManager to move a directory from one location to another, and I gave the user the option to cancel the operation; to workaround the NSFileManager's 'un-cancellability', I just *renamed* the destination directory while its contents are being copied; NSFileManager raises an error and the copy operation cleanly stops. This will only work for moves between volumes or copies, though (where a copy or copy-delete is done), because for moves within a volume, OSX just does a rename, which is practically instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving the file as the previous post suggested, but the move does not cause the copyItemAtURL to return with an error. It seems that Apple deprecated a method that has no replacement with the equivalent functionality.